# Amadeus self service api details on specific offer returns error

Tags: java, amadeus

I'm trying to use hotel offer details api on amadeus self service. Unfortunately i got the above error. The request is based on a specific offer id from hotel search api.

> {
>     "errors": [
>       {
>         "status": 400,
>         "code": 367,
>         "title": "INVALID FORMAT"
>       }
>     ]
>   }

PS: i get the same response even if i use the website form for the request.

Comment: Can you provide your request and/or your code?

Comment: The problem occurs even if i do the request from postman or amadeus portal. So the postman request is : `GET @ https://test.api.amadeus.com/v2/shopping/hotel-offers?cityCode=MAD&adults=1`. Then i get the offer id from the response of the above request and my new request is: `GET @ https://test.api.amadeus.com/v2/shopping/hotel-offers/ACEAFD861B92F434E82E02805A42F6E9E6DE8EEDA31B35D5395860E8ABD2AF04`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems that the offer you are trying to get doesn't exist anymore, this could come from:

You got the offer id from `https://test.api.amadeus.com/v2/shopping/hotel-offers?cityCode=MAD&adults=1`. This API as some cached data, that will explain why the offer doesn't exist anymore. In addition, you are using the test environment where you access to a subset of our production with a much lower refresh rate.

What you can do is to call the 2nd endpoint of Hotel `/shopping/hotel-offers/by-hotel?hotelId={hotelId}`. This endpoint doesn't use cache data. If you still have the error at this moment it is because of the limitations of the test environment, you will have to move to production to unlock access to the full set of data and full refresh of data.